# how to display the image in portion of pannel control using vb.net 2.0

Tags: vb.net, runtime, image

I want  to display the image in panel control when mouse move on specific portion of panel control. Panel control already have a picture.\
How its possible?

Comment: I have no idea what you're trying to do. Can you provide a better description and/or a picture?

Answer (score 0):

Please explain in more detail,

If I am correct then you are saying that "You want to add second image in same Panel which already has some image" if right?....then you can use

```
panel1.Controls.Add(new Image("~path"))
```